# Navigation Bar: Second level with full width

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I created a navigation bar with a first and second level navigation. You can see the latest version here as a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aytaxykf/4/) (maybe you have to increase the width of the frame containing the output to see the navigation bar with two levels).

At the moment, I have several issues with this navigation bar:

1. The width of the first level element "Menu1" should only be the width which it will need and not the width of the total width of the elements inside the second level navigation.
2. The second level navigation should be width 100% so the same as the yellow header and not only the width of the elements of the second level navigation bar.

So the navigation bar should look like the following image:
[image: Navigation bar how it should look like]

But how can this be achieved, especially the width of 100% of the second level navigation bar? I tried this [CSS-Tricks: Full Browser Width Bars](https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/) with "Using pseudo elements", because I did not want to have this definition globally on

```
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/aytaxykf/5/
i added this ontop of your styling. so you can probably remove some of the rules you have there

```
.top-bar {
  position: relative;
}
.top-bar-section {
  height: 70px;
}
ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
  text-align:center;
}
ul.sub-menu li{
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
.menu-center a {
  position: relative;
}

.menu-center .active > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent lime transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It works great! Only one more thing. In my image you can see how the navigation should look like and there is an additional 1px solid white line. If the second level navigation won't be displayed, then there should this line below the yellow navigation header part. If the second level navigation displayed, then the white line should be as in my image (on two sides of the triangle). Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Just add a border top to submenu ul

Comment: The line should be displayed always and not only if there is a sub-menu. And with the triangle, the white line should flow around the triangle, this is not possible with only a border-top: 1px solid white;.